# Regular expression help - comma delimited string

Tags: regex, vb.net

I don't write many regular expressions so I'm going to need some help on the one.

I need a regular expression that can validate that a string is an alphanumeric comma delimited string.

Examples:

- `123, 4A67, GGG, 767` would be valid.
- `12333, 78787&*, GH778` would be invalid
- `fghkjhfdg8797<` would be invalid

This is what I have so far, but isn't quite right: `^(?=.*[a-zA-Z0-9][,]).*$`

Any suggestions?

Comment: Your regular expression means "match if the next bit matches, but don't consume, any one char, then one of a-z, A-Z, or 0-9, followed by one of: a comma. Then consume any one character before the end of the string." It is impossible for this to match anything, since the not consuming part must match three characters, including a trailing comma, before the consuming part comes and can only match one thing.

Comment: @markets: The OP didn't use code formatting, so the two `*` quantifiers weren't visible.  The regex is still wrong, but it makes a little more sense now. ;)  @JohnH: You'll get better results if you use SO's formatting tools; they're very good.

Answer (score 37):

Sounds like you need an expression like this:

```
^[0-9a-zA-Z]+(,[0-9a-zA-Z]+)*$
```

Posix allows for the more self-descriptive version:

```
^[[:alnum:]]+(,[[:alnum:]]+)*$
^[[:alnum:]]+([[:space:]]*,[[:space:]]*[[:alnum:]]+)*$  // allow whitespace
```

If you're willing to admit underscores, too, search for entire words (`\w+`):

```
^\w+(,\w+)*$
^\w+(\s*,\s*\w+)*$  // allow whitespaces around the comma
```

Comment: A few problems with this answer: (1) A POSIX "character class" can't be used directly; it has to be enclosed in another set of square brackets, e.g. `[[:alnum:]]+`.  But that's academic since .NET doesn't support them (not even in different form, like Java's `\p{Alnum}`). (2) `\w`, like all character-class shorthands (`\s`, `\d`, etc.), matches exactly one letter, so you should have used `\w+`. (3) You didn't allow for whitespace between tokens.

Comment: @Alan: Thank you, fixed! By the way, what's "whitespace" in Emacs? `\s` doesn't seem to work...

Comment: I don't use Emacs, but according to [this](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/RegularExpression), it's `\s-`.  The `\s` itself doesn't match anything; it just marks the following character as special.

Answer (score 8):

Try this pattern: `^([a-zA-Z0-9]+,?\s*)+$`

I tested it with your cases, as well as just a single number "123". I don't know if you will always have a comma or not.

The `[a-zA-Z0-9]+` means match 1 or more of these symbols
The `,?` means match 0 or 1 commas (basically, the comma is optional)
The `\s*` handles 1 or more spaces after the comma
and finally the outer `+` says match 1 or more of the pattern.

This will also match
`123 123 abc` (no commas) which might be a problem
This will also match `123,` (ends with a comma) which might be a problem.

Answer (score 3):

Try the following expression:

`/^([a-z0-9\s]+,)*([a-z0-9\s]+){1}$/i`

This will work for:

1. test
2. test, test
3. test123,Test 123,test

I would strongly suggest trimming the whitespaces at the beginning and end of each item in the comma-separated list.

Answer (score 2):

You seem to be lacking repetition. How about:

```
^(?:[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+,)*[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$
```

I'm not sure how you'd express that in VB.Net, but in Python:

```
>>> import re
>>> x [ "123, $a67, GGG, 767", "12333, 78787&*, GH778" ]
>>> r = '^(?:[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+,)*[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+$'
>>> for s in x:
...    print re.match( r, s )
...
<_sre.SRE_Match object at 0xb75c8218>
None
>>>>
```

You can use shortcuts instead of listing the `[a-zA-Z0-9 ]` part, but this is probably easier to understand.

Analyzing the highlights:

- `[a-zA-Z0-9 ]+` : capture one or more (but not zero) of the listed ranges, and space.
- `(?:[...]+,)*` : In non-capturing parenthesis, match one or more of the characters, plus a comma at the end. Match such sequences zero or more times. Capturing zero times allows for no comma.
- `[...]+` : capture at least one of these. This does not include a comma. This is to ensure that it does not accept a trailing comma. If a trailing comma is acceptable, then the expression is easier: `^[a-zA-Z0-9 ,]+`

Comment: This allows spaces anywhere, so it would also match `' abc 123, fo o bar '`.  Maybe that's acceptable to the OP, but I would pull the spaces out of the character classes.

Comment: @Alan good point. OP didn't address spaces at all but permitted them in the examples. The regex could remove the existing spaces and add optional spaces (space-star) before and after the comma.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, when you want to catch comma separated things where a comma at the end is *not* legal, and the things match to `$LONGSTUFF`, you have to repeat `$LONGSTUFF`:

```
$LONGSTUFF(,$LONGSTUFF)*
```

If `$LONGSTUFF` is really long and contains comma repeated items itself etc., it might be a good idea to *not* build the regexp by hand and instead rely on a computer for doing that for you, even if it's just through string concatenation. For example, I just wanted to build a regular expression to validate the CPUID parameter of a [XEN configuration file](http://xenbits.xen.org/docs/unstable/man/xl.cfg.5.html), of the `['1:a=b,c=d','2:e=f,g=h']` type. I... believe this mostly fits the bill: (whitespace notwithstanding!)

```
xend_fudge_item_re = r"""
  e[a-d]x=          #register of the call return value to fudge
  (
    0x[0-9A-F]+ |   #either hardcode the reply
    [10xks]{32}     #or edit the bitfield directly
  )
"""
xend_string_item_re = r"""
  (0x)?[0-9A-F]+:   #leafnum (the contents of EAX before the call)
  %s                #one fudge
  (,%s)*            #repeated multiple times
""" % (xend_fudge_item_re, xend_fudge_item_re)
xend_syntax = re.compile(r"""
  \[                #a list of
   '%s'             #string elements
   (,'%s')*         #repeated multiple times
  \]
  $                 #and nothing else
""" % (xend_string_item_re, xend_string_item_re), re.VERBOSE | re.MULTILINE)
```

Comment: Please be aware that the above RE has a few issues, including but not limited to lack of whitespace support and case sensitivity, that make it not production-worthy. The fixed version is quite a lot longer and then you'd start missing the point of the answer. It's just an example of how to handle more complicated cases sanely.

Comment: I didn't end up using that regexp - so [here's the full shebang](https://gist.github.com/badp/6353579)

Answer (score 1):

Try `^(?!,)((, *)?([a-zA-Z0-9])\b)*$`

Step by step description:

- Don't match a beginning comma (good for the upcoming "loop").
- Match optional comma and spaces.
- Match characters you like.
- The match of a word boundary make sure that a comma is necessary if more arguments are stacked in string.

Comment: This is the only answer that doesn't repeat the pattern. Should get more upvotes.

Answer (score 1):

Please use - ^((([a-zA-Z0-9\s]){1,45},)+([a-zA-Z0-9\s]){1,45})$

Here, I have set max word size to 45, as longest word in english is 45 characters, can be changed as per requirement