# Regular Expression for comma separated words

Tags: php, regex

I want to replace some string like

```html
Category : Entertaiments, Movie,Music, Super Natural, Hobbies
```

(even with inconsistent comma and space placing) To be like this

```html
Category : <a href="http://someurl/entertaiments">Entertaiments</a>, <a href="http://someurl/movie">Movie</a>, <a href="http://someurl/music">Music</a>, <a href="http://someurl/super-natural">Super Natural</a>, <a href="http://someurl/hobbies">Hobbies</a>
```

I already tried to use `\w+(?=[,])`, but it cant work perfectly

Comment: What is the difference between the first one and the second ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regular expression help - comma delimited string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6448573/regular-expression-help-comma-delimited-string)

Comment: Can you edit the question to say whether you ask about the matching only, or the replacement too?

Comment: @SylvainAttoumani : comma and spacing

Comment: @VolkerSiegel : Edited. Im asking for replacement, so i can place the url on it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need use regex try this:

```
$string = 'Category : Entertaiments, Movie,Music, Super Natural, Hobbies';
$string = preg_replace('/,(\S)/',', $1', $string);
```