# Whats the difference between using a class and interface?

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript, structural-typing

What is the difference between doing this

```
export class Comment {
  likes: string;
  comment: string;

  constructor(likes: string, comment: string){
    this.comment = comment;
    this.likes = likes;
  }
}
```

and this

```
export interface CommentInterface {
  likes: string;
  comment: string;
}
```

in relation to declaring an observable type

```
register: Observable<CommentInterface[]> {
    return this.http.get()
}
```

Comment: http.post() will never return an instance of your class. Because all http does is parse the body to JSON, which produces basic JavaScript objects.It won't instantiate your class.

Comment: I think this question is very clear and should not be closed. Why? Because the Angular documentation is full of examples of using `class` instead of `interface` for just this thing. And `interface` is the correct choice when declaring XHR responses.

Comment: I was only using it as an example. I changed it to get and login so it makes more sense

Comment: The exact same thing is true for http.get(). It takes the response body and parses it to JSON; And that won't produce instances of any class.

Comment: The second snippet is **not** an interface: `export class LoginInterface`. It's a class.

Comment: I think you mean 'export interface LoginInterface', don't you, not 'export class LoginInterface', otherwise your examples are both the same.

Comment: @cartant Thanks. I changed it to interface

Comment: An interface gets erased at compilation, and only has an impact during type checking. A class is an actual runtime artifact, and you can implement concrete methods and properties inside it.

Comment: @AsadSaeeduddin A `class` is unsuitable for declaring a type that respresents an an HTTP response. Use `interface` or `type` instead.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6448573/regular-expression-help-comma-delimited-string

Answer (score 12):

As JB Nizet quite correctly points out, the deserialized JSON values that result from HTTP requests will never be instances of a class.

While the dual role (see below) of the `class` construct in TypeScript makes it possible to use a `class` to describe the shape of these response values, it is a poor practice because the response text will be deserialized into plain JavaScript objects.

**Class declarations in JavaScript and TypeScript:**

In JavaScript, a class declaration

```
class Comment {
  constructor(likes, comment) {
    this.likes = likes;
    this.comment = comment;
  }
}
```

creates a value that can be instantiated using `new` to act as what is essentially a factory.

In TypeScript, a class declaration creates *two* things.

The first is the exact same JavaScript class *value* described above.
The second is a *type* that describes the structure of the instances created by writing

```
new Comment(4, 'I love your essays')
```

That second artifact, the type, can then be used as a type annotation such as in your example of

```
register(): Observable<Comment[]> {
    return this.http.get()
}
```

which says that `register` returns an `Observable` of Arrays of `Comment` `class` instances.

Now imagine your HTTP request returns the following JSON

```
[
  {
    "likes": 4,
    "comment": "I love you oh so very much"
  },
  {
    "likes": 1,
    "comment": "I lust after that feeling of approval that only likes can bring"
  }
]
```

However the method declaration

```
register(): Observable<Comment[]>;
```

while it correctly allows callers to write

```
register().subscribe(comments => {
  for (const comment of comment) {
    if (comment.likes > 0) {
      likedComments.push(comment);
    }
  }
});
```

which is all well and good, it unfortunately also allows callers to write code like

```
getComments() {
  register().subscribe(comments => {
    this.comments = comments;
  });
}

getTopComment() {
  // since there might not be any comments
  // it is likely that a check will be made here
  const [topComment] = this.comments.slice().sort((x, y) => y - x);

  // BUG! Always false at runtime.
  if (topComment instanceof Comment) {
    return topComment;
  }
}
```

Since comments are not actually instances of the `Comment` class the above check will always fail and hence there is a bug in the code. However, TypeScript will not catch the error because we said that `comments` is an array of instances of the `Comment` class and that would make the check valid (recall that the `response.json()` returns `any` which can be converted to any type without warnings so everything appears fine at compile time).

If, however we had declared comment as an `interface`

```
interface Comment {
  comment: string;
  likes: number;
}
```

then `getComments` will continue to type check, because it is in fact correct code, but `getTopComment` will raise an error at compile time in the if statement because, as noted by many others, an `interface`, being a compile time only construct, can not be used as if it were a constructor to perform an `instanceof` check. The compiler will tell us we have an error.

---

**Remarks:**

In addition to all the other reasons given, in my opinion, when you have something that represents *plain old data* in JavaScript/TypeScript, using a class is usually overkill. It creates a function with a prototype and has a bunch of other aspects that we do not likely need or care about.

It also throws away benefits that you get by default if you use objects. These benefits include syntactic sugar for creating and copying objects and TypeScript's inference of the types of these objects.

Consider

```
import Comment from 'app/comment';

export default class CommentService {    
  
  async getComments(): Promse<Array<Comment>> {
    const response = await fetch('api/comments', {httpMethod: 'GET'});
    const comments = await response.json();
    return comments as Comment[]; // just being explicit.
  }

  async createComment(comment: Comment): Promise<Comment> {
    const response = await fetch('api/comments', {
      httpMethod: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify(comment)
    });
    const result = await response.json();
    return result as Comment; // just being explicit.
  }
}
```

If `Comment` is an interface and I want to use the above service to create a comment, I can do it as follows

```
import CommentService from 'app/comment-service';

export async function createComment(likes: number, comment: string) {    
  const commentService = new CommentService();
  
  await commentService.createCommnet({comment, likes});
}
```

If `Comment` were a class, I would need to introduce some boiler plate by necessitating the `import` of `Comment`. Naturally, this also increases coupling.

```
import CommentService from 'app/comment-service';
import Comment from 'app/comment';

export async function createComment(likes, comment: string) {    
  const commentService = new CommentService();
  
  const comment = new Comment(likes, comment); // better get the order right

  await commentService.createCommnet(comment);
}
```

That is two extra lines, and one involves depending on another module just to create an object.

Now if `Comment` is an interface, but I want a sophisticated class that does validation and whatnot *before* I give it to my service, I can still have that as well.

```
import CommentService from 'app/comment-service';
import Comment from 'app/comment';

// implements is optional and typescript will verify that this class implements Comment
// by looking at the definition of the service method so I could remove it and 
// also remove the import statement if I wish
class ValidatedComment implements Comment {
  constructor(public likes, public comment: string) {
    if (likes < 0 || !Number.isSafeInteger(likes)) {
      throw RangeError('Likes must be a valid number >= 0'
    }
  }
}

export async function createComment(likes, comment: string) {
  const commentService = new CommentService();
  
  const comment = new ValidatedComment(likes, comment); // better get the order right

  await commentService.createCommnet(comment);
}
```

In short there are many reasons to use an `interface` to describe the type of the responses and also the requests that interact with an HTTP service when using TypeScript.

**Note:** you can also use a `type` declaration, which is equally safe and robust but it is less idiomatic and the tooling around `interface` often makes it preferable for this scenario.

Answer (score 8):

As in most other OOP languages: For classes you can create instances (via their constructor), while you cannot create instances of interfaces.

In other words: If you just return deserialized JSON, then it makes sense to use the interface to avoid confusion. Lets assume you add some method `foo` to your `Comment` class. If your `register` method is declared to return a `Comment` then you might assume that you can call `foo` on the return value of register. But this wont work since what `register` effectively returns is just deserialzed JSON without your implementation of `foo` on the `Comment` class. More specifically, it is NOT an instance of your `Comment` class. Of course, you could also accidentally declare the `foo` method in your `CommentInterface` and it still wouldn't work, but then there would be no actual code for the `foo` method that is just not being executed, making it easier to reason about the root cause of your call to `foo` not working.

Additionally think about it on a semantic level: Declaring to return an interface gurantees that everything that is declared on the interface is present on the returned value. Declaring to return a class instance gurantees that you... well... return a class instance, which is not what you are doing, since you are returning deserialized Json.

Comment: Nice +1. Might be worth mentioning the `instanceof` hazard as well, that is a trap that many fall into.