# How to organize classes for an Angular application?

Tags: javascript, angular, api, class, structure

What is the most professional way to handle the response of an API using classes in TypeScript, JavaScript, Java or whatever else?

For example, an application needs three ressources:

- Account (API: /account/:id)
- Car (API: /account/:id/cars/[:id])
- Driver (API: /account/:id/cars/:id/drivers)

Every **Account** has one or more **Car**s, every **Car** has one or more **Driver**.

I see two ways to handle these resources in my application:

1. Create a class for each ressource (Account, Car, Driver) **and nest it**. E.g.

   ```
   class Account {
     constructor(
       public id: number,
       public name: string,
       public age: number
       public cars: Car[]
     ) {}
   }

   class Car {
     constructor(
       public id: number,
       public type: string,
       public seats: number
       public drivers: Driver[]
     ) {}
   }
   ```

   In this case, the API would return an already nested JSON response and it would only be necessary to request the data once.
2. Create a class for each resource **but don't nest it**. First get only account data (calling /account/1234), then drivers if needed and cars if needed at a late date of the application lifecycle.

   ```
   class Account {
     constructor(
       public id: number,
       public name: string,
       public age: number
     ) {}
   }

   class Car {
     constructor(
       public id: number,
       public type: string,
       public seats: number
     ) {}
   }
   ```

   In this case the API would return for each API call only the main resource data.

So should resources always be nested over the complete application and called up only at one time, or should the resource classes exist and be reloaded independently of each other in the application? Which way is used by professional programmers?

Comment: Why do you need to create classes in the first place? What behaviour do you intent do add to them? If you don't intend to add methods, the classes aren't really necessary; you'd be better of defining TypeScript interfaces for the resources.

Comment: Your question content is nothing to do with Angular class organisation. What you're asking about is API design; your DTO classes/interfaces in Angular should reflect what you're getting from the backend.

Comment: This is to ambiguous. When designing you also have to consider how you want to use the data and how big the data sets are likely to be in a single hit. Nesting would be fine on small data sets, but you wouldn't want to do it this way if the datasets are always large.(think about the network traffic then multiply by the amount of users that are likely to use your site).

Comment: It's only an opinion. I like the hard-work is made in the server (not in client), so, my first aproach will be the API return nested classes. But you can need in your application see all cars, or all drivers. Depending the size of the data would have a service was which nested the classes. Well, we are talking about classes (use interface, because you needn't a method of the object, only data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*[A class is unsuitable for declaring a type that represents an HTTP response. Use interface or type instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45405240/5695162)*

**From Angular Style Guide**

> Consider using an interface for data models

Angular 4.3 has  introduced new easier way to handle `http` requests with the `HttpClient` library

> You can tell `HttpClient` the type of the response to make consuming
>   the output easier and more obvious. 
>   All you need to do is define an interface for the shape of the response and type-check against that interface:

```
    interface Post {
      title: string;
      body: string;
    };

    // ...

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

    getData() {
      this.http.get<Post>(this.url).subscribe(res => {
        this.postTitle = res.title;
      });

}
```

> So should resources always be nested over the complete application and
>   called up only at one time, or should the resource classes exist and
>   be reloaded independently of each other in the application? Which way is used by professional programmers?

*It entirely depends on your use case*