# How to convert json response into an object without explicitly coding it in TypeScript (Angular 6)?

Tags: json, angular, api, casting

In my little project, part of the functionality is to manage project entities. I created a class that looks like this:

```
export class IdRef {
  id: number;
}

export class Project {
  id?: number;
  title: string;
  background?: string;
  problemStatement?: string;
  owner: IdRef;
  createdBy: IdRef;
  dateCreated: string;
  updatedBy?: IdRef;
  lastUpdated?: string;

  getDateCreated(): Moment {
    return moment(this.dateCreated);
  }

  getLastUpdated(): Moment {
    if (this.lastUpdated) {
      return moment(this.lastUpdated);
    }

    return undefined;
  }
}
```

The idea is to get a list of these objects when I fetch a list of projects from API call.

The service function that fetches the list is:

```
public getProjects(): Observable<Project[]> {
    const projectListUrl = `/v1/api/project`;

    return this.http.get<Project[]>(environment.apiDomain + projectListUrl)
      .pipe(
        catchError(this.networkService.handleError)
      );
  }
```

And I am using it like that (in a controller):

```
loadProjects() {
    this.projectService.getProjects()
      .subscribe(
        (projects: Project[]) => {
          console.log(`fetched ${projects.length} projects`);
          this.projects = projects as Project[];
        },
        error => this.error = error
      );
  }
```

The expectation that I had from all this, is that I will actually get a list of Project objects; however, the value of `this.projects` in the controller is an array of json objects instead, so there is no way I can use any functions of Project without building the objects explicitly.

Is there a way to "cast"/parse json into an object to get a real object?
How?

Comment: It's just a type hint: TypeScript *does not exist at runtime*, so cannot do any casting or conversion. You have to convert the raw response explicitly yourself if you want methods or properties other than valid JSON values.

Comment: Good point... didn’t think about it :)

Comment: Do Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45404571/whats-the-difference-between-using-a-class-and-interface/45405240#45405240)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, the typecast in your http.get just concerns the shape of the returned objects (i.e. the properties), not the methods.

The easiest way to convert one of these property-only objects to an actual instance of the desired object it to use Object.assign, as in `Object.assign(new MyObject(), jsonObject)`

So, for instance,

```
return this.http.get<Project[]>(environment.apiDomain + projectListUrl)
      .pipe(
        map(jsonObj => Object.assign(new Project(), jsonObj),
        catchError(this.networkService.handleError)
      );
```