# How to design typescript model for response?

Tags: angular, typescript

How do I design my model in typescript where I got below response?

```
{
    "data":[
            {
                "name": "XYZ",
                "id": "1"
            },
            {
                "name" :"Abc",
                "id": "2"
            }
        ]
}
```

what I tried :

```
export class responseModel<T>{
    data:T;
}

export class model{
    name:string;
    id: number;
}
```

What is your recommendation? all data will come as part of `{ data: THE_DATA_OBJECT }`

```
{
    data: []
}

getInfo(): Observable<responseModel<model[]>> {
    // API HTTP Call
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*[A class is unsuitable for declaring a type that represents an HTTP response. Use interface or type instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45405240/5695162)* because the deserialized JSON values that result from HTTP requests will never be instances of a class

> [`@Angular StyleGuide`](https://angular.io/guide/styleguide#interfaces) 
> Consider using
>   an interface for data models.

```
export interface Model{
        id: number;
        name: string;
    }

export interface ResponseModel{
         data:Array<Model>;
  }

getInfo(): Observable<responseModel>{
return this._httpClient.get<resposneModel>('url);
}
```

Comment: all my services is returning {data = [ {item}] }, so what should i do in that case? for each response we need to create 2 interface?

Comment: and what if wanted to use same model for data submit in reactive forms ? for example : const a = new model(); a.name="name1"  ==> and a will be submit to http.post request.

Comment: `all my services is returning {data = [ {item}] }` yes , apart from it You should be aware of the fact that the TypeScript compiler uses interfaces solely for type-checking purposes interfaces does not exists at run-time.

Comment: @Var For second scenario you should use class not an interface

Comment: @Var An interface is a group of related properties and methods that describe an object, but neither provides implementation nor initialisation for them.

Comment: `for each response we need to create 2 interface? ` Depends on the response you are getting if its same you can reuse the model else create a new one

Answer (score 0):

`data` should have type `model[]` and whole response type is `responseModel`

```
export class responseModel{
   data:model[];
}
export class model{
  name:string;
  id: number;
}

getInfo(): Observable<responseModel> {
// API HTTP Call
}
```

Comment: all my services is returning {data = [ {item}] }, so what should i do in that case? for each response we need to create 2 interface?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a subjective question so I'll share my experiences when I was having a similar situation.

All of the backend endpoints for my project responses with `{ data: THE_DATA_OBJECT }`. I think it's a bit redundant to design all of my response models starts with a "data" prefix, so instead of doing that, I basically unwrap the "data" prefix in my api service.

Something like the following:

```
genericHttpCall<T>(path: string, method: string, params: any}: Observable<T> {
  return this.httpClient.request().pipe(map(response => response.data));
}
```

So basically that saves me from doing `class responseModel<T>` so that I can focus on design the real model freely instead of let backend affect my model structure.

Also, I always use `interface` instead of `class` for response model because they are plain data model that involves no constructor or methods. Unless you want to make the model works for your business logic.