# HttpClient how to convert nested json and map to model domain

Tags: json, angular, observable, httpclient, amadeus

Hi I am pretty new to programing and i have been looking for an answer on the web for days for my problem without finding anything that works for me no matter what i do. I am receiving nest json as response. The json object amongst other things seem to have a dynamic key. What i want is to transform the json object to my model so that i can easily access the data in my template. Appreciate any help

here is an example of the json data 
[Amadeus API response](https://sandbox.amadeus.com/travel-innovation-sandbox/apis/get/flights/affiliate-search)

Here is my service

```
getResults(params: any) {
  this.getItiniraries(params).subscribe((res) => {
    this.itinirary = res;
    // console.log(res);
    this.updatedResults.next(this.itinirary);
  });
}


getItiniraries(params: any): Observable<Itinirary> {
  return this.http.get<Itinerary>('http://localhost:4202/api/itinirary' ,  {params: params})
  ; }
```

the models

Itinirary model

```
import { Result } from './result.model';
import { Meta } from '@angular/platform-browser';

// Model for data from Amadeus flight affiliate search

 export class Itinirary {

 public meta: Meta;
 public results: Result[];
 constructor(res: any) {
  this.meta = res.meta;
  this.results = res.results;
```

}
}

Result Model

```
   import { Flight } from './flight.model';
    import { Fare } from './fare.model';


   export class Result {
   public outbound_duration: string;
   public outbound_flights: Flight[];
   public inbound_duration: string;
   public inbound_flights: Flight[];
   public fare: Fare;
   public cabin_code: string;
   public fare_family: string;
   public travel_class: string;
   public merchant: string;
   public airline: string;
   public deep_link: string;
   constructor(result: any) {
   this.outbound_duration = result.outbound.duration;
   this.outbound_flights = result.outbound.flights;
   this.inbound_duration = result.inbound.duration;
   this.inbound_flights = result.inbound.duration;
   this.fare = result.fare;
   this.cabin_code = result.cabin_code;
   this.fare_family = result.fare_family;
   this.travel_class = result.travel_class;
   this.merchant = result.merchant;
   this.airline = result.airline;
   this.deep_link = result.deep_link;
   }
   }
```

Flight model

```
import { BookingInfo } from './bookingInfo.model';


export class Flight {
public departs_at: Date;
public arrives_at: Date;
public marketing_airline: string;
public operating_airline: string;
public flight_number: number;
public aircraft: number;
public booking_info: BookingInfo;
public origin_airport: string;
public origin_terminal: string;
public destination_airport: string;
public destination_terminal: string;
constructor(flight: any) {
this.departs_at = flight.departs_at;
this.arrives_at = flight.arrives_at;
this.marketing_airline = flight.marketing_airline;
this.operating_airline = flight.operating_airline;
this.flight_number = flight.flight_number;
this.aircraft = flight.aircraft;
this.booking_info = flight.booking_info;
this.origin_airport = flight.origin_airport;
this.origin_terminal = flight.origin_terminal;
this.destination_airport = flight.destination_airport;
this.destination_terminal = flight.destination_terminal;
```

}
}

Meta model

```
    import { Carrier } from './carrier.model';

export class Meta {
public carriers: {[key: string]: Carrier };
constructor(meta: any) {
this.carriers = meta.carriers;
}
}
```

Carrier Model

```
export class Carrier {
public identifier: string;
public name: string;
public logoSmall: string;
public logoMedium: string;
constructor(carrier: any) {
this.identifier = carrier;
this.name = carrier.name;
this.logoSmall = carrier.logos.samll;
this.logoMedium = carrier.logos.medium;
}
}
```

in my flight model i would also like to add two properties date and time that derives from departure_at and arrival_at.

Basically i want to be able to pass the whole Intinirary object to my view so that i can through string iterpolation get the values.

ex after using ngFor or let result of itinirary.results

{{ result.outbound_flights[0].departure_date }} etc.

would really appreciate good guidance

updated service

```
  getItiniraries(params: any): Observable<any> {
  return this.http.get<any>('http://localhost:4202/api/itinirary' ,  
  {params: params})
  .pipe(map((AmdResponse) => {
    const parsedRes = JSON.parse(AmdResponse);
    const itin = new Itinirary(parsedRes);
    return itin;
  } )); }
```

Updated meta Model and carrier Model
Meta

```
import { Carrier } from './carrier.model';

export class Meta {
public carriers: {[key: string]: Carrier };
constructor(meta) {
this.carriers = {};
Object.keys(meta.carriers).forEach(code => {
this.carriers[code] = new Carrier(meta.carriers[code]);
});
}
}
```

carrier model

```
export class Carrier {
public name: string;
public logoSmall: string;
public logoMedium: string;
constructor(cObject ) {
Object.keys(cObject).forEach(code => {
  this.name = cObject.name;
});
Object.keys(cObject.logo).forEach(code => {
this.logoSmall = cObject.logos.samll;
this.logoMedium = cObject.logos.medium;
});
}
}
```

I also updated my Result model like this. Does it make sense?

```
import { Flight } from './flight.model';
import { Fare } from './fare.model';


export class Result {
public outbound_duration: string;
public outbound_flights: Flight[];
public inbound_duration: string;
public inbound_flights: Flight[];
public fare: Fare;
public cabin_code: string;
public fare_family: string;
public travel_class: string;
public merchant: string;
public airline: string;
public deep_link: string;
constructor(result) {
this.outbound_duration = result.outbound.duration;
// this.outbound_flights = this.loop(this.outbound_flights, 
 result.outbound.flights);
this.inbound_duration = result.inbound.duration;
// this.inbound_flights = this.loop(this.inbound_flights, 
result.inbound.flights);
this.fare = new Fare(result.fare);
this.cabin_code = result.cabin_code;
this.fare_family = result.fare_family;
this.travel_class = result.travel_class;
this.merchant = result.merchant;
this.airline = result.airline;
this.deep_link = result.deep_link;

  for (let i = 0; i < result.outbound.flights.length; i++) {
    this.outbound_flights[i] = new Flight(result.outbound.flights[i]);
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < result.inbound.flights.length; i++) {
    this.inbound_flights[i] = new Flight(result.inbound.flights[i]);
  }


  }
  // loop(a, b) {
  //   for (let i = 0; i < b.length; i++) {
  //     a[i] = new Flight(b[i]);
  //   }
  //   return a;
  // }
  }
```

I tested both with a function or seperate loop.

I also added a dateFormatterService in my flight model, was not sure though where to import it to as i could not import it to constructor.

```
import { BookingInfo } from './bookingInfo.model';
import { DateFormatterService } from '../../Shared/dateFormatter.service';


export class Flight {
private df: DateFormatterService; // can i have it here instead of constructor?
public departs_date: string;
public departs_time: string;
public arrives_date: string;
public arrives_time: string;
public marketing_airline: string;
public operating_airline: string;
public flight_number: number;
public aircraft: number;
public booking_info: BookingInfo;
public origin_airport: string;
public origin_terminal: string;
public destination_airport: string;
public destination_terminal: string;
constructor(flight: any ) { 
const depart_at = new Date(flight.departs_at);
const arrive_at = new Date(flight.arrives_at);

this.departs_date =  this.df.transformDate(depart_at);
this.departs_time = this.df.transformTime(depart_at);
this.arrives_date = this.df.transformDate(arrive_at);
this.arrives_time = this.df.transformTime(arrive_at);
this.marketing_airline = flight.marketing_airline;
this.operating_airline = flight.operating_airline;
this.flight_number = flight.flight_number;
this.aircraft = flight.aircraft;
this.booking_info = new BookingInfo(flight.booking_info);
this.origin_airport = flight.origin_airport;
this.origin_terminal = flight.origin_terminal;
this.destination_airport = flight.destination_airport;
this.destination_terminal = flight.destination_terminal;
}}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/52443768/5695162

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a preamble, understand there is no way to receive a JSON string (from an API or elsewhere) and make it become an instance of a specific custom Class.

I think you started with the right idea in your Meta constructor.... that you need to parse the received data into your own objects.  You just need to go further, by explicitly parsing all properties of the received JSON into new objects (of your classes) one at a time until you're done.  Tedious, maybe, but required if you want your own class hierarchy to represent the received data (which may NOT be needed, but that's not for me to decide).

I assume you've already got a JS literal object from the data received from the API response, something like this:

```
const itins = JSON.parse( amadeusResponse );
```

Then, you let your classes do the work:

```
const meta = new Meta( itins.meta );
//or
const alternate = new Meta();
alternate.fromJSON( itins.meta );
```

By the above, you can see you can either have a method that reads JSON data, or a constructor.  The choice would be made by whether you would expect to ever create a Meta object without first having the JSON (in which case the method alternate is likely better).

In either case, the implementation reads the JS object you give it, and parses the received data structure into the structure you want to have in your local class instances.  For example, in the Meta constructor...

```
constructor( meta ) {
    this.carriers = {};
    // which carriers did we get?
    Object.keys(meta.carriers).forEach( code =>
        this.carriers[code] = new Carrier( code, meta.carriers[code] )
    );
```

In turn, the Carrier class constructor will read the "logos" and "name" properties, either into its fields, which may include even more class instances.

Keep going, until you're done.

Comment: Hi, Slash thank you for your answer, i think this is the correct path for me to take, but even after think for quite a bit I am not fully sure how to implement it. I have post more could please look again.

Comment: could you elaborate more on this please. One thing is how do I now use the code(two letter carrier code) and the meta.carriers[carrier object] to create my carrier object in my carrier class. Could you please illustrate using one full example, maybe meta to carriers and all the content of that object. Also the const meta = new Meta, should i do that in the map, or  subscription or where would be most suitable. I changed my service, see the updated question. Also how could I break down the date, time to just date and time in the class constructor?

Comment: The next step is in the Carrier constructor, you do the same as in the Meta constructor... set properties from in inbound JSON object.   Also, remember you don’t necessarily have to make your local classes exactly like the received data.... make your local objects work for you in the app.   What I mean is, take the data you received, and put it into a data format that works best for you.

Comment: Hi in general i wanna keep the classes as they are, i think they have a good structure, its only those two points that i want to change, the date and time. And also this problem of meta.

Comment: @Shark I updated my Meta and Carrier and also flight based one what i understood from your explanations, is this in right direction? I didnt send code(two letter arline code) to carrier as i couldnt undrestand what to do with it.

Comment: @Eddie if the dates your receive are in a standard (i.e. ISO) format, you can get a javascript property in your object with this.departs = Date.parse(itinerary.departs).   That date contains both date and time.   Also, the 'moment' library is a popular alternative to javascript Date.

Comment: @Eddie  I just saw DateFormatterService.  You don't even need to make it a private variable in your class.  Just call DateFormatterService.formatTime( departs )  directly.   Also note that instead of creating new fields inside your class, you could just create a method in the class the gets the time for your Date property:  getTime() { return DateFormatterService.formatTime( this.departs ); }.    Beyond this, I think we're at risk of turning this question into a tutorial session, which is probably not in line with StackOverflow guidelines.  Good luck with your learning... Have fun!

Comment: and Youko Thank you very much guys for your help, i understand that its going towards a tutorial and I am sorry for that.  I have revisited the typescript class model again, to refresh my knowledge and see if i can combine that with the knowledge I have gained from your guys :), Hopefully once I have finished the code maybe you could have a look at it. thanks again guys.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a tree of Javascript instances of models from JSON, you can map the JSON to the root class constructor like this:

```
getItiniraries(params: any): Observable<Itinerary> {
   return this.http.get<Itinerary>('http://localhost:4202/api/itinirary',  {params: params}).pipe(map(x => new Itinerary(x)); 
}
```

Then define the following constructor for all of your model classes:

```
constructor(obj) {
   Object.assign(this, obj);
}
```

Then for all the children of a model class, replace these declarations `public meta: Meta;` with:

```
private _meta: Meta;

get meta() {
   return this._meta;
}

set meta(value: any) {
   this._meta = new Meta(value);
}
```

Same goes for children as `Array`:

```
private _results: Result[];

get results() {
   return this._results;
}

set results(value: any) {
   this._results = value.map(x => new Result(x));
}
```

Then your tree of objects will be composed of instances of your model classes, and you'll be able to benefit from the potential functions you'll define (for example data formatting functions, or whatever else)

Comment: Hi Youku thanks for you answer. But will i be really able to use object.assign, as the name and the structure of the recieved data is not exactly the same my model classes.

Comment: Also i want to have one nested object that i can access and retrieve whatever info i need from that instead of accessing several objects/arrays with different get functions.

Comment: @Eddie if you need something more specific than `Object.assign()`, then define your own constructor. I'm sorry I don't get your last comment, the `get` and `set` keywords aren't real functions, but accessors to a property and can be used with `itinerary.meta = value` and `let value = itinerary.meta`

Comment: I am really trying to undrestand what you and Shark are writing but i guess my knowledge level is to low, as i dont undrestand all aspects of it. I apologise if I am asking to basic questions, But if you have time please answer my following questions as well. Am i right that in order to use object.assign the properties of the obj and the target object(this) need to be exactly same, for the object assign to match them and pass over obj to target(this)? If that is the case then i could use it for those objects that will remain same as response obj?

Comment: But for those that i want to change i need to define it in my constructor like Shark mentioned below. For get and set meta could you give me an example of how i could for ex call set meta() from my itinerary class. Also how could i then later get them in my view with theses accessors. Lets say i am looping through the results and i want to get the outbound.flight[0].departs_at. How would i access this with get access?

Comment: Yes `Object.assign()` is the thing to use when the target properties are the same as the source properties. If you want to define a specific constructor, then don't use `Object.assign()` and do it by hand. About the `set` and `get` you have to understand they define a custom behavior for setting a value into a property and reading a value from a property, then your can use the property like any other property. With this pattern, your parent will just set children in its constructor, then the subsequent `set` will take care of instantiating an object

Comment: Hi guys, so now i have managed to map the json object to my own object model by parsing each property and it works when using subscription in the component , however when I try to render the observable inside HTML without subscribe using async pipe it fails show cannot read property results of undefined. I have tried different ways but I am still not able to get it to work. Any ideas? Br Eddie

Answer (score 0):

using new es6 features it is quite easy `this._results = value.map(x => new Result(x));` can be`this._results = [...value]` this case if value is nested json array it will be flat as you want.