# Regex rules for comma separated list

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a regex for a string input of a comma separated list. I turn the list from the input into an array so it needs to be validated on input. Right now I have this `/^([a-z0-9\s]+,)*([a-z0-9\s]+){1}$/i` and it works with most cases but it doesnt work when there is a comma and space at the end of the string. When I run array split on it, it takes the empty string after the comma and sets it to null. Is this something that can be done on the regex side or on the spliut method? This is when I convert the string of comma separated inputs into an array: `replace(/\s/g, '').split(',')`

Comment: You don't need `{1}`, since that's the default.

Comment: Split the string using comma as the delimiter, and remove the last element if it's empty.

Comment: Try `replace(/^[,\s]+|[,\s]+$|\s/g, '').split(',')`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regular expression help - comma delimited string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6448573/regular-expression-help-comma-delimited-string)

Answer (score 0):

Split on optional space, comma, optional space. Remove empty array items if needed:

```js
const input = [
  'aaa, bbb,ccc',
  'ddd, eee , fff, ',
  ', ggg, hhh, , iii'
];

input.forEach((str) => {
  let result1 = str.split(/ *, */);
  let result2 = result1.filter(Boolean);
  console.log('"' + str + '"');
  console.log('- result1: ' + JSON.stringify(result1));
  console.log('- result2: ' + JSON.stringify(result2));
});
```

Output:

```
"aaa, bbb,ccc"
- result1: ["aaa","bbb","ccc"]
- result2: ["aaa","bbb","ccc"]
"ddd, eee , fff, "
- result1: ["ddd","eee","fff",""]
- result2: ["ddd","eee","fff"]
", ggg, hhh, , iii"
- result1: ["","ggg","hhh","","iii"]
- result2: ["ggg","hhh","iii"]
```

Explanation:

- `/ *, */`- splits on optional space, followed by comma, followed by optional space
- result1: shows the result of the split
- result2: if you want to get rid of empty array items, filter out using `.filter(Boolean)`

If you want to preserve empty array items except at the end, remove the comma at the end before the split: `str.replace(/[, ]+/, '').split(/ *, */)`

Comment: @hernandeΩ: does that answer your question? Let me know if not. If so, I'd appreciate if you accept the answer.